# How do I reverse the Sort?

Tags: java, sorting

As of now I wrote the program, and it sorts the students scores from lowest to highest. I need to reverse it where it sorts from highest to lowest.

```
public static void sortStudentScores(String namesArry[], int scoresArry[]) {
    int tempScore;
    String tempName;

    for (int i = 0; i < scoresArry.length; i++) {

        for ( int j= i + 1; j < scoresArry.length; j++) {

            if (scoresArry[i] > scoresArry[j]) {
                tempScore = scoresArry[i];
                scoresArry[i] = scoresArry[j];
                scoresArry[j] = tempScore;
                tempName = namesArry[i];
                namesArry[i] = namesArry[j];
                namesArry[j] = tempName;

            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("\nAscending Order:");

    for (int i = 0; i < namesArry.length; i ++) {
        System.out.println("Student Name: " + namesArry[i] + " " + scoresArry[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: try changing this condition .. if (scoresArry[i] > scoresArry[j])

Comment: Changing `>` to `<`?

Comment: Just reverse the array after sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void sortStudentScores(String namesArry[], int scoresArry[]) {
    int tempScore;
    String tempName;

    for (int i = 0; i < scoresArry.length; i++) {

        for ( int j= i + 1; j < scoresArry.length; j++) {

            if (scoresArry[i] < scoresArry[j]) {
                tempScore = scoresArry[i];
                scoresArry[i] = scoresArry[j];
                scoresArry[j] = tempScore;
                tempName = namesArry[i];
                namesArry[i] = namesArry[j];
                namesArry[j] = tempName;

            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("\nDescending Order:");

    for (int i = 0; i < namesArry.length; i ++) {
        System.out.println("Student Name: " + namesArry[i] + " " + 
scoresArry[i]);
    }
}
```

Here just the logic for sorting has been modified, in your code you ensured that the element at smaller index has smaller score. To do it in descending order, you just need to do the opposite.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

update your code as below:

```
if (scoresArry[i] < scoresArry[j])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you define a class Student and define your comparator for sorting (see: http://www.baeldung.com/java-sorting)